# UnityWebRequest with cookie authentication

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i was trying to get a data with an user profile API where you need cookies authorization to make it work, and i can't really get and/or set the cookies for the target website.
here's the code that i'm currently using(to get the data from target url), the cookie that act as authorization was called .AspNet.ApplicationCookie

```
    IEnumerator GetData_Coroutine()
{

    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get("Target URL"))
    {

        if (cookie != "")
        {
            request.SetRequestHeader(".AspNet.ApplicationCookie", "Content in it");
            

        }

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.result== UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
        {
            outputArea.text = request.error;

        }
        else
        {

            
            
            
            if (outputArea != null)
            {
                outputArea.text = request.downloadHandler.text;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and here's the outcome i've got[image: and here's the outcome i've got]

p/s: i'm quite new to networking. So feel free to point out if there's any mistakes that i'm not aware of

Comment: You almost certainly need to do the login and capture the cookie. Not just supply a cookie

Comment: looks like you successfully downloaded the login page ^^

Comment: thing is, i need to use the cookie for authentication

Answer (score 0):

After several trial and error, turns out that my mistake comes from the header name from SetRequestHeader
it's name should be the header, while the content should be the whole thing it has

you should be able to see it from web debugger, while the text shown is their name you should put first, their content will be the second one
[image]

so the code should be like this:

```
    public string cookieContent
    IEnumerator GetData_Coroutine()
    {
    
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get("Target URL"))
        {
    
            if (cookie != "")
            {
                request.SetRequestHeader("cookie", cookieContent);
                
    
            }
    
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();
            if (request.result== UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError || request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError)
            {
                outputArea.text = request.error;
    
            }
            else
            {
    
                
                
                
                if (outputArea != null)
                {
                    outputArea.text = request.downloadHandler.text;
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```